# Is this a cyclic dependency

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis, cyclic-dependency

```java
class foo{
Bar b;
}

class bar{
Class clazz = foo.class;
}
```

Does the above snippet show a cyclic dependency. Class foo has a reference of bar class object. Class bar has reference to foo class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the specifics can be slightly different depending on the language you use, in more pure object oriented terms, no.

It can be helpful to look at Smalltalk-inspired languages like Ruby to see how this is the case:

```rb
class Foo
    def initialize()
        @b = Bar.new()
    end
    def what_is_b() # instance method can call class method who
        @b.who()
    end
    def who()
        "foo instance"
    end
    def self.who() # class method can't call instance method what_is_b
        "foo class"
    end
end

class Bar
    def initialize()
        @clazz = Foo
    end
    def what_is_clazz()
        @clazz.who()
    end
    def who()
        "bar instance"
    end
    def self.who()
        "bar class"
    end
end

f = Foo.new()
puts f.who()
puts f.what_is_b()

puts " and "

b = Bar.new()
puts b.who()
puts b.what_is_clazz()
```

This outputs:

```
foo instance
bar instance
 and 
bar instance
foo class
```

This shows that a `foo instance` has-a `bar instance`, and a `bar instance` has-a `foo class`. In pure OO, a `foo class` is a factory for `foo instances`, and class methods cannot reference instances methods, but the reverse is true, so `foo instances` can depend on `foo class` but not the other way around.

So in this contrived example, `foo instance` is the head of the dependency tree, while `foo class` is the tail. If instead of referencing the Foo class in the clazz instance variable you referenced a `foo instance` you would have a cyclic dependency graph